# Columns from a List<?> property. Is it possible in dynamic jasper?

Tags: java, dynamic-jasper

Dynamic Columns from a Hashmap property in DynamicJasper. Is it possible?

Hi,I'm really new to Dynamic Jasper. I'm having some trouble with some columns that should come from a property of Hashmap. I'll put a example to be clearer:

```
class Product {
 private String name;
 private String price;
 private String whatever;
 private Hashmap<String,String> comments;
}
```

My DataSource is a `List<Product>` of products;

```
|__name___|___price___|_____whatever_____|______First item inside the comments list_____|___Second item inside the comments list____|___N item inside the comments list __|
```

the name of the columns will be the same as key in the hashmap.and value is the value of the hashmap.
every object(product) has a hashmap with different comments(values) but same keys.for example:

```
product1: name1,price1, hashmap: ("quality","good")("easyToUse","yes")
product2: name2,price2, hashmap: ("quality","bad")("easyToUse","no")
```

and the report should be like this:

```
|__ name_______|______price _____|_____quality_____|______easyToUse______|

|___name1_____|______price1_____|______ good_____|______ yes___________|

|___name2_____|______price2_____|______ bad______|______ no____________|
```

Is it possible or should I try another approach?
how can I create columns dynamically?and set them correct value?

Best Regards

Comment: what do you mean by column ?? did your tried any code ?

Comment: Do you mean a `toString` method where you first print name, value, whatever and then the list of comments?

Comment: @RimonMostafiz i found this : http://www.dynamicreports.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=170
but I could not use it. =(

Comment: @aimee no.every product object has a hashmap. the key is column name and the value is value of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is iterate over every key inside the products, for each one print the name of the product, its price, the key and the corresponding value.

```
for(Product p : Products){
    for(String key : p.comments.keySet()){
        System.out.println(p.name +", " + p.price", "+ key +" " + p.comments.get(key));
    }
 }
```

Comment: thank you. but it is not as easy as an itteration on a hashmap. I want to create columns Dynamically with Dynamic Jasper. it won't be solved with an easy itteration =(